# Show view in middle while navigation like UITextfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, zooming

I am working on app where I have many views like `UILabel`,`UITextfield`, `UIButton` and etc and all are in `UIScrollView` and also zooming is enable so user can view a single item too. I also have navigation say next button on pressing next this highlight items one by one on some highlighting order. 
Issue is when user zoom in and on pressing next button focus should be on that item which is in order, its working perfectly fine on `UITextfield` because when on `becomFirstResponder` open keybaord and move focus to that text field but I want this same feature for others too like buttons and labels?
Looking for solution to whom already worked on this kind of work.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may scroll to the position of the next object when the `next` button is tapped.

```
yourScrollView.center = yourObject.center
yourScrollView.setContentOffset(yourScrollView.frame.origin, animated: true)
```

And to scroll back to top

```
scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 0), animated: true)
```

Comment: I done this but its show on right top corner instead of showing me in center